# how mysql_real_escape_string work

Tags: php

How does mysql_real_escape_string work?  Does it delete mysql functions or add // between mysql function?  Is it better than addslashes

Comment: Delete or add what? Yes its better then addslashes.

Comment: IMO its better to trust, most of the time, something that works than to re-recreate if that's what u are talking about

Comment: @user553786: Please go accept some answers on your previously asked question. I'd also suggest you start using punctuation.

Answer (score 4):

mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.

IMO, its better to use this function than attempting to recreate, most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

When sanitizing database inputs you should always use `mysql_real_escape_string` over `addslashes` and other not native PHP *functions* unless you are using the newer PDO library.

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Source@ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

You should also be aware that PHP has provided a native Library called **PDO** which is a class that manages your database sanitization so you do not have to worry to much.

Prepared statements are handled by the database service itself, this increases security and performance over all.

If you wish to implement prepared Statements you would need to learn and incorporate PDO Are another native database abstraction layer.

To implement PDO [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

To learn more about Prepared Statements [Click Here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Nothing else? Numeric input, they need to be verified as numeric.

Comment: that's validation not sanitization

Comment: "Only ever rely on this function and nothing else." Or, rely on prepared queries, which are generally better.

Comment: Yes, my point is choose real escape over add slashes, Prepared statements are much better but the question was specifically about the native function.

Comment: Please clarify your answer then. In its current state it is wrong

Comment: Jesus, you guys are way to picky, I answer these questions day in and day out.