# Why is it desirable to escape/strip this character from user provided data?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP’s mysql_real_escape_string and MySQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279973/phps-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-injection)

This is the character in question:

```
\x1A
```

Why does it pose a threat and what is it? Googling says it's a control character but I don't understand what that means, especially in the context of escaping data.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP's mysql\_real\_escape\_string and MySQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279973/phps-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-injection/679449) and [how mysql_real_escape_string work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007774/how-mysql-real-escape-string-work/679449)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x1A` is ctrl-z, which in DOS days was used as an EOF (end-of-file) marker. While it shouldn't be a problem on any modern database, it could have been used to sneak extra query statements past an old dos-days SQL parser, so you'd end up with something like:

```
UPDATE scores SET points=points+1
ctrl-z
DROP TABLE scores
```

A stupid parser would stop at the ctrl-z, thinking "hey, look, it's the end of the file". The entire string would be passed to the DB, and if it was a "smart" db, would ignore the ctrl-z and happily execute the drop command